# Beautiful Soup not finding Div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get products for a project i'm working on from this page:
[Belk.com](http://www.belk.com/AST/Main/Belk_Primary/Women/Shop/Accessories.jsp)

I originally tried going very specific using

```
soup.find("ul", {"class" : "product_results"})
```

Nothing was happening, so I went very broad and just started searching all divs.

```
contentDiv = soup.find_all("div")
for div in contentDiv:
    print(div.get("class"))
```

When I do this I am getting only Div's for the top half of the page, which lead me to believe that there is an iframe that I wasn't getting into, but upon closer inspection I couldn't find the frame. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Its likely being loaded with JavaScript, although I can't say for certain without visiting the page. Try disabling JavaScript in your browser and refreshing the page. Inspect the source after doing this and look for the `<div>`. If its missing, JavaScript is to blame and you'll have to use something else to find the element; perhaps Selenium.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.belk.com/AST/Main/Belk_Primary/Women/Shop/Accessories.jsp')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

res = soup.find('ul',{"class":"product_results"})
lis = res.findAll('li')
for j in lis:
    #your code
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I was pulling the file from a text document, and forgot to remove the new line at the end, which was through the page request off. Thanks.